# pyparsing trouble accessing ParseResults

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a ParseResults object, which looks like this when I dump it:

```
[[['FM4', '230', '30', '680']]]   
[0]:   
     [['FM4', '230', '30', '680']]   
     [0]:   
       ['FM4', '230', '30', '680']   
       - FormNumber: 'FM4'   
       - BookNum: '680'   
       - PageNum: '230'   
       - BookmarkNum: '30'
```

I can't seem to access the results by the name.

For example: `results.FormNumber`
Or,

```
for i in results:   
    print("i dict", dict(i))   

results in:   
        ('i dict', {})
```

If I print :

```
print("i list", list(i))
```

I get :

```
('i list', [(['FM4', '230', '30', '680'], {'BookmarkNum': ['30'], 'BookNum': 
['680'], FormNumber: ['FM4'], 'PageNum': ['230']})])
```

How can I access the dictionary object by name?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code that gives you this result?

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review of my grammar, I realized I was using a Group, which resulted in creating a list and not a dictionary.

After removing the group, this:
    ('i list', [(['FM4', '230', '30', '680'], {'BookmarkNum': ['30'], 'BookNum': 
['680'], FormNumber: ['FM4'], 'PageNum': ['230']})])

Becomes this: ('i list', [(['FM4', '230', '30', '680'], {'BookmarkNum': '30', 'BookNum': 
'680', FormNumber: 'FM4', 'PageNum': '230'})])

And, then I was able to use the dictionary by name

Thanks